# hi, trying to add another element to an array but it keeps coming up as error on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def take_a_number (array,element)
 array.push element
 puts "Welcome, #{element}. You are #{} in line."


end
```

1) Deli Counter #take_a_number there is nobody in line should add a person to 
the line
    Failure/Error: take_a_number(katz_deli, "Ada")

```
  #<IO:<STDOUT>> received :puts with unexpected arguments                  
    expected: ("Welcome, Ada. You are number 1 in line.")                  
         got: ("Welcome, Ada. You are  in line.")                          
# ./deli_counter.rb:21:in `puts'                                           
# ./deli_counter.rb:21:in `take_a_number'                                  
# ./spec/deli_counter_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Welcome, #{element}. You are **#{}** in line.
```

you need to pass a value in **#{}**, at present will return/put blank, hence why your test is failing.
So passing array.length, array.size or even array.count will resolve your issue

for example

```
Welcome, #{element}. You are #{array.length} in line.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for your test you need to add where the last element is in your string interpolation. Maybe something like this.

```
def take_a_number(array, element)
  array.push(element)
  puts "Welcome, #{element}. You are #{array.size} in line."
end
```